# Проверка уникальности email при регистрации django

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь создать регистрацию на django. Столкнулся с проблемой, не могу проверить уникальность поля email при регистрации.

### ursl.py

```
path('accounts/register/', MyRegisterFormView.as_view(), name="register"),
```

---

### forms.py

```
class Register(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

---

### views.py

```
class MyRegisterFormView(FormView):
# Указажем какую форму мы будем использовать для регистрации наших пользователей, в нашем случае
# это UserCreationForm - стандартный класс Django унаследованный
form_class = Register

# Ссылка, на которую будет перенаправляться пользователь в случае успешной регистрации.
success_url = "/accounts/login/"

# Шаблон, который будет использоваться при отображении представления.
template_name = "registration/register.html"


def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    return super(MyRegisterFormView, self).form_valid(form)

def form_invalid(self, form):
    return super(MyRegisterFormView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

---

Как можно реализовать это?

```
if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
     messages.error(request, "Эта почта уже зарегестрированна")
```

Я понимаю что нужно сравнить email с фильтром и при совпадении вернуть ошибку, но не могу реализовать это. Как можно обратиться к полю формы email во views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не понятно зачем ты в форму добавляешь еще одно поле email, если оно уже есть у модели User

```
class Register(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean(self)
        if User.objects.filter(email=cleaned_data.get('email')).exists():
            self.fields.add_error('email', "Эта почта уже зарегестрированна")
        return cleaned_data
```

после этого ты в шаблоне можешь обращаться к ошибкам формы
`{{form.email.errors}}`